# Understanding Haskell Type Class use in Type Declarations

Tags: haskell

When we have a function that compares two things using the `==` comparison operator we add something like `Eq a => a...` to the type declaration; but this doesn't always seem to be the case.

For example, given the following function:

```
tail' xs = if length xs == 0
          then []
          else drop 1 xs
```

We make use of the `==` comparison operator, so I assumed the correct type decalaration would be:

```
tail':: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
```

However, running `:t tail'` tells me that the correct type decalartion is:

```
tail':: [a] -> [a]
```

Why is this the case? Why isn't `Eq` required in the type declaration?

Comment: You should use pattern matching where possible (e.g. here), rather than reach for `==`. Also some time take a few minutes to study how lists are defined and consider what, as a consequence, the time complexity of common array-like operations like `length`, `last`, or `!!` must be.

Comment: Note also that `drop 1 []` is already `[]`, although I understand that that's not the point of your question :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Eq a => t` says that `a` must be an instance of `Eq` in the type `t`. A type being an instance of `Eq` means that `==` is defined for that type. But in your definition of `tail'`, you never use `==` on an `a`, not even by proxy. The actual use of `==` is in `length xs == 0`. The type of `length xs` (and `0`) is `Int`, and `Int` is already an instance of `Eq`, so we already know it has `==` defined. Since you never use `==` on an `a`, you don't need an `Eq a` constraint.

If, however, you had said `xs == []`, which seems equivalent (both test whether a list is empty), you would have incurred an `Eq a` constraint. This is because `==` on `[a]` requires an `Eq a` constraint since it uses `==` on each list's entries to compare the lists. Since you can use `length xs == 0` (or, even better, `null xs`), though, this added constraint is spurious and should be avoided.

(As an aside, `drop 1 [] = []` so you don't even need your `if`, but that isn't relevant to the question asked.)